# Read XML from InputStreamReader and write it to file

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, stream

My code receives an `XML` `String` from an `InputStreamReader` (it's actually the output of `REST` request to another server) and then the `String` is written to a file (file includes not only `XML`).

The problem is that the `String` is received as one line of `XML` and so it's stored as one huge line in the file (no indentation, tabs, formatting etc.).

Can I receive this `XML` stream and format it while writing it to the file?

Note: I can't use DOM here, it must be implemented without loading the XML to memory.

Comment: As string `replaceAll("</[\\w:]+>", "$0\r\n")`. For indentation more is needed. Also this migh not be adequate for some tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `Transformer` and `SAX`, if you are allowed to :-

```
public static void prettyPrintXmlToFile(String sourceXml, File targetFile) throws Exception{
    Transformer serializer = SAXTransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    serializer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
    Source xmlSource = new SAXSource(new InputSource(new StringReader(sourceXml)));
    StreamResult res = new StreamResult(targetFile);
    serializer.transform(xmlSource, res);
}
```